# Переназначение локальных переменных ref

Tags: c#, .net

В [новом обновлении](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) завезли

> Переназначение локальных переменных ref. Локальные переменные и
>   параметры ref теперь можно переназначить с помощью оператора
>   присваивания ref (= ref)

1. Для чего это может потребоваться?
2. Как этим пользоваться? Что-то попробовал после обновления применить

   var t = new object();
           object t2 =null;
               t2= ref t;
   однако, ловлю ошибку.

Comment: это для структур, чтобы меньше копировалось

Comment: @Grundy, попробовал со структурами выполнить код, который я описал и все равно не присваивается.

Comment: Потому что я перепутал с немного другим похожим :-)

Comment: потому что `ref object t2`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да. Так работает. Теперь остался вопрос с мотивацией.

Comment: [Ref locals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals)

Comment: @Grundy, понятно. Однако, не могу представить когда бы мне понадобилось бы иметь 2 ссылки на 1 значимый тип, что бы мне нужно было поведение, что по всем ссылкам выполнялось изменение.

Comment: @iluxa1810, например, массив структур, получается конкретный элемент, изменяется - меняется значение в массиве

Comment: @Grundy, хм... Ну тогда все понятно.

Comment: Оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для использования `ref` переменных [*в определении переменной так же должен стоять `ref`*](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals), поэтому код должен выглядеть так:

```
var t = new object(); 
ref object t2 = ref t;
```

Применить это можно, например, при работе со структурами.

Например, имеется массив структур, и нужно изменить значение в нулевом элементе.

Так как это структура, без `ref` изменение значения поля включило бы в себя два копирования: одно для получения элемента, второе - для сохранения нового элемента.

В случае с `ref` обойдется вообще без копирования элемента.